# Fix value trying to be set on a copy of a slice in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to change all the dates in a dataframe column to european format, but am getting the error:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

And most of the answers I've seen don't apply as I am iterating over dataframes in a for loop:

```
for FTID in Training_Dict:
    Training_Dict[FTID]['TransDate'] = pd.to_datetime(Training_Dict[FTID]['TransDate'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
```

I am not sure what format this should be in to fix the error

Comment: Most likely because each `Training_Dict[FTID]` is a part of a bigger dataframe.

Comment: They are, does that mean that fixing it is impossible?

Comment: You can fix it by `bigger_data.loc[Training_Dict[FTID].index, 'TransDate'] = ...`. But why don't you convert that bigger dataframe instead? Something like `bigger_data['TransDate'] = pd.to_datetime(bigger_data['TransDate'])`.

Comment: Hadn't considered just completing the action over the entire dataframe, most of the processing involves using subsets and I've only started using pandas for this project so following tutorials mostly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of using pd.to_datetime() use .dt.strftime()

```
for FTID in Training_Dict:
        Training_Dict[FTID]['TransDate'] = Training_Dict[FTID]['TransDate'].dt.strftime("%d-%m-%y")
```

P.S.:
can you please show what's there in Training_Dict?

Comment: Getting an attribute error with that ````Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values````

Comment: if possible can you let me know what training_dict is ?

Comment: I have changed to completing it over the full dataframe so now it is ````df['TransDate']```` where  dates are in the format 26/06/2019 11:08

Comment: try this: `df= pd.to_datetime(df['TransDate'],format='%m/%Y/%d')`
`df["TransDate"]=df['TransDate'].dt.strftime("%d-%m-%y")`

Comment: and the datatype of 'TransDate' is also  datetime?